# Qu'est-ce qu'un « pays de peuplement » ?

Tags: sens

[Cet article](https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/1964/05/COEDES/25987) du *Monde diplomatique*, intitulé « Un pays de peuplement très ancien dont l’histoire prend une consistance réelle à la fin du Vlle siècle », commence comme suit :

> L'Indonésie est un pays de peuplement très ancien, et l’on a trouvé a
> Java les restes de certains des plus vénérables spécimens de la race
> humaine, tel le fameux pithécanthrope dans le pléistocène.

Le terme n'y apparait pas plus et n'y est pas non plus expliqué. Que signifie-t-il ?

Answer (score 5):

Ce n'est pas un "pays de peuplement" mais un pays de/au "peuplement très ancien", c'est à dire qu'il y a très longtemps que ce pays est habité.

Answer (score 2):

Ce terme semble provenir du vocabulaire anthropologique ou bien des études de migration d'Homo sapiens dont les migrations ont peuplé des territoires de plus en plus isolés.
Dans ce contexte, le peuplement signifie donc le début de la présence humaine sur le territoire de ce pays.